# Error while activating publishing feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing

I have created site collection and activated SharePoint publishing infrastructure and SharePoint server publishing feature.

But When I tried to activate "SharePoint Server Publishing" Feature in sub site. I got following error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something went wrong with the Publishing Infrastructure feature activation.

The content type mentioned in the screenshot is of Page content type created by Publishing feature.

To resolve the issue:

1. Go to Site Settings
2. Click Site collection features
3. Deactivate the 'SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure' feature
4. Reactivate the 'SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure' feature
5. Go back to Site Settings
6. Click Manage site features
7. Activate the 'SharePoint Server Publishing' feature